# Error while signing android bundle: Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I was trying to build a release build of Flutter android app and got following error: (Macbook M1 using terminal command)

```
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.                     
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException (no error message)
```

I've no idea how to fix this issue.
The android/app/build.gradle of relevant part looks like:

```
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had almost the same problem:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException (no error message)
```

In my case, there was a typo in my `key.properties` file. I had `keyPasswork` instead of `keyPassword` and now everything is working fine. I suggest OP checks this file, too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Bingo, when building new flavor bundle I forgot to add new flavor key store alias and password into my untracked file `keystore.properties`. Thank you. I have found this answer quickly from google search :) You saved me several minutes (hours?) of debugging what is wrong.

Comment: I typed "kayPassword". Thanks for pointing out the obvious

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the file `build.gradle` under android/app had a typo in it

```
     signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Check if this is right. Sometimes, the typo could be that instead of writing `storePassword`, it's written `storeP assword`

Comment: In my case it was a typo in the key.properties file. I accidentally mis copied the block from Google docs. `torePassword` instead of `storePassword`.